# Are there rules for cutting/removing an enemy's bow string during combat?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, attack

If a Rogue gets into melee combat with another combatant wielding a bow, what actions are permitted to disable the bow?

Could the Rogue use Sleight of Hand to unhinge the bow string?

Could he make a melee attack to cut the string or destroy the bow or does he have to disarm the opponent and make him drop his weapon before he may destroy it?

I couldn't find any rules on how to handle such a situation as a DM.